# play framework receive paypal IPN request

Tags: java, paypal, playframework, paypal-ipn

I tried to send an IPN (from the simulator) to my play framework url!

the url looks like that: http://host/checkout/sub

Server is running on port 80. The problem is that the ipn request doesn't even call the linked method. (So the method that i just defined in the routes is never called, if I request an ipn), but still there is an incoming request!

If i try to call the URL via browser, I don’t experience any problems and the method is called properly.

So did anyone else face that problem?
Should I try another way?

Help is very appreciated!

Kind Regards,
Paul

Edit: I get that exception after about 5 minutes

[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[netty-3.9.8.Final.jar:na]

Comment: Is http://host publicly accessible?  Meaning it can be reached from other servers on the net.

Comment: well, i guess it should be? since i can reach it with the browser? do i have to make some configurations to make it explicitly accessible from other servers?! 
kind regards

Comment: It is possible to have a local site that can be viewed with a browser but not accessed by PayPal.

Comment: Hi! PayPal is reaching the server! I started the server and sent an ipn to it... then it compiled etc. ... still the method isn't called and i get "We're sorry, but there's an HTTP error. Please try again."

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Finally...

1) I had to fix some settings at my service provider (Open Internet -> yes)

2) I had to change the port to 80 (was on 9000 for testing)

3) The exceptions by play and paypal didnt really say anything... wireshark did, once again, a good job: in my routes files i defined the rout as GET but of course they are sending their data via POST (stupid mistake :P)

Kind regards